# How to calculate the average birthyear of offspring in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, count, average

I would like to know the average birthyear of the direct offspring per individual. The package 'pedigree'has a function (countOff) that calculates all offspring, including the grand-offspring, which is not what I want. This is my dataframe (df):

```
ID <- 1:30
MomID <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1,2,1,2,6,8,6,10,11,13,16,19,16,13,16,20,19,16,19,20,23)
DadID <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,3,4,5,5,7,4,9,7,7,14,18,7,15,18,18,17,21,14,18,21,17)
Birthyear <- c(1975, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1977, 1977, 1977, 1978, 1978, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1982, 1984, 1984, 1985, 1985, 1985, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1995, 1995, 1996)
df <- dataframe(ID,MomID, DadID, Birthyear)

   ID MomID DadID Birthyear
1   1    NA    NA      1975
2   2    NA    NA      1975
3   3    NA    NA      1976
4   4    NA    NA      1977
5   5    NA    NA      1977
6   6    NA    NA      1977
7   7    NA    NA      1977
8   8    NA    NA      1978
9   9    NA    NA      1978
10 10     1     3      1980
11 11     2     4      1981
12 12     1     5      1982
13 13     2     5      1982
14 14     6     7      1984
15 15     8     4      1984
16 16     6     9      1985
17 17    10     7      1985
18 18    11     7      1985
19 19    13    14      1988
20 20    16    18      1989
21 21    19     7      1990
22 22    16    15      1990
23 23    13    18      1991
24 24    16    18      1992
25 25    20    17      1993
26 26    19    21      1993
27 27    16    14      1993
28 28    19    18      1995
29 29    20    21      1995
30 30    23    17      1996
```

To do this I would need to count for every individual the number of offspring they have, and then average the birthyears of those offspring. The number of offspring for each individual can be another column in the dataframe, same goes for the average birthyear of the offpsring. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A perhaps less convoluted, and more "baby steps", approach:

Just lookup when ID is Mom, look up when ID is Dad, get the birth year, count and average it.

```
    df %>%
        left_join( df, c("ID" = "MomID") ) %>%                                ## Add offspring if mom

        left_join( df, c("ID" = "DadID") ) %>%                                ## Add offspring if dad

        mutate( BirthyearOffspring = coalesce( Birthyear.y, Birthyear ) ) %>% ## Merge birthyears to one column

        group_by( ID ) %>%                                                    ## Always need to group when making summaries

        summarize(
            OffspringAvgBirthyear = mean( BirthyearOffspring, na.rm=TRUE ),   
            OffspringCount        = length( BirthyearOffspring )
        ) %>% print.data.frame # to see digits
```

Output:

```
    #    ID OffspringAvgBirthyear OffspringCount
    # 1   1              1981.000              2
    # 2   2              1981.500              2
    # 3   3              1980.000              1
    # 4   4              1982.500              2
    # 5   5              1982.000              2
    # 6   6              1984.500              2
    # 7   7              1986.000              4
    # 8   8              1984.000              1
    # [...]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have noticed though that for the individuals that do not have any offspring at all (individuals 12, 22, and 25 up to 30) your code still gives OffspringCount == 1 when it should in fact be 0. Any idea why that is? (your answer was very clear btw, super helpful)

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out! I changed the `OffspringCount = length(BirthyearOffspring[!is.na( BirthyearOffspring )])` and then only individuals with offspring have an OffspringCount.

Comment: Cool! Nothing better than seeing students starting to teach their teachers!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want

```
df2 <- df %>% pivot_longer(c(MomID, DadID), names_to = "parent_type", values_to = "parent_id") 

df2 %>% left_join(df2, by = c("ID" = "parent_id"), suffix = c("p", "o")) %>%
  select(-parent_typep) %>% group_by(ID, IDo) %>% slice_head() %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(OffspringCount = n(),
            AvBirthYear = mean(Birthyearo))

      ID OffspringCount AvBirthYear
 * <dbl>          <int>       <dbl>
 1     1              2       1981 
 2     2              2       1982.
 3     3              1       1980 
 4     4              2       1982.
 5     5              2       1982 
 6     6              2       1984.
 7     7              4       1986 
 8     8              1       1984 
 9     9              1       1985 
10    10              1       1985 
# ... with 20 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mean` in `sapply` and subset `df$Birthyear` using `df$ID`:

```
df$AvBirthYear <- sapply(df$ID, function(i) mean(df$Birthyear[df$MomID == i |
           df$DadID==i], na.rm=TRUE))
 head(df)
#  ID MomID DadID Birthyear AvBirthYear
#1  1    NA    NA      1975      1981.0
#2  2    NA    NA      1975      1981.5
#3  3    NA    NA      1976      1980.0
#4  4    NA    NA      1977      1982.5
#5  5    NA    NA      1977      1982.0
#6  6    NA    NA      1977      1984.5
```