# IF function to change data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

So, I have a large pedigree consisting of individuals, parents, year of births and average year of birth for the individuals offspring.
To be clarify with an example: for Individual 5 the year of birth is 1900. This is not possible because its parents are born in 1975 and 1977. Individual 5 also has offspring with year of birth. A common method to "fix" missing or faulty year of birth data is to subtract the generation interval from average year of birth from the offspring. So, for individual 5, average year of birth of the offspring is 1983, so 1983 - 5 = 1978. I tried to code it using the IF function, but it did not work as I got two errors (pasted below). Would case_when and mutate work better?

```
Indiv <- c(1:10)
Mother <- c(NA, NA, NA, 2, 3, 3, 6, 3, 8, 8)
Father <- c(NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 5, 4, 4, 9)
YOB <- c(1975, 1975, 1977, 1980, 1900, 1982, 1983, NA, 1988, 1993)
AvgYOBOff <- c(1954, 1981, 1943, 1988, 1983, 1983, NA, 1990.5, 1993, NA)
df <- data.frame(Indiv, Mother, Father, YOB, AvgYOBOff)
L = 5 #generation interval of 5 years

if(df$YOB < df$YOB[match(df$Mother, df$Indiv)] & df$YOB[match(df$Father, df$Indiv)]){
   mutate(df, YOB = AvgYOBOff - L)
}
```

```
Error in if (df$YOB < df$YOB[match(df$Mother, df$Indiv)] & df$YOB[match(df$Father,  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In if (df$YOB < df$YOB[match(df$Mother, df$Indiv)] & df$YOB[match(df$Father,  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: You are checking condition for a vector, but mutating a dataframe?  What if your condition is false?

Comment: For individual 1, `AvgYOBOff`is 1954, but `YOB`is 1975 - can that be correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the average birthyear of offspring in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66332551/how-to-calculate-the-average-birthyear-of-offspring-in-r)

Comment: How is this different to your previouis question(s)?

Comment: @AnilGoyal if the condition is false, then the YOB should not change. I do not necessarily want to mutate the dataframe, I just want the YOB (in the dataframe) to change IF the offspring's birthdate occurs before its parents

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Yes that's correct because individual 1 fathered individual 5, whose YOB is 1900. Obviously the YOB of individual 5 is not correct. But it is quite a common thing to see. Basically the 1900 indicates a missing birthyear (but tells you the individual was born after 1900).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first get the indices where `YOB` is less than corresponding `Mother` or `Father` values and subtract those `AvgYOBOff` values with `L`.

```
inds <- which(df$YOB < df$YOB[match(df$Mother, df$Indiv)] | 
              df$YOB < df$YOB[match(df$Father, df$Indiv)])

df$YOB[inds] <- df$AvgYOBOff[inds] - L
```

Answer (score 0):

I can also use the ifelse function

```
df$YOB <- ifelse(df$YOB < df$YOB[match(df$Mother, df$Indiv)] | 
                 df$YOB < df$YOB[match(df$Father, df$Indiv], df$AvgYOBOff - L, df$YOB)
```